# Having trouble loading data from database

Tags: iphone, sql, xcode

I'm running through a tutorial on how to load data from a SQlite database. The table populates fine but when I go to a detailed view and try load additional data the app crashes. The console shows the following error.

```
-[NSPlaceholderString initWithDouble:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance
```

Here is my code.

```
if (SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(detailStmt)) {
        NSString *address = [[NSString alloc]initWithDouble:sqlite3_column_double(detailStmt, 0)];
        self.ClubAddress = address;
        [address release];
```

I know the problem is with "`initWithDouble:sqlite2_column_double`" but I'm unsure how to fix it. would much appreciate some help.

Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try this...

if (SQLITE_DONE != sqlite3_step(detailStmt)) {
       double add = sqlite3_column_double(detailStmt, 0)];
        NSString *address = [NSString strinWithFormat:@"%f",add];
        self.ClubAddress = address;
        [address release];
}

Comment: Hang on No it didn't. I now get weird stuff were my text should be. Any more help.@Chetan Bhalara

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a string you can do the following:

```
NSString *address = [[NSNumber numberWithDouble:sqlite3_column_double(detailStmt, 0)] stringValue];
```